# Changing in Cassandra Source Is Not Reflecting Outside of Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, cassandra

I am working on a project where I need to change the source code of Cassandra. I downloaded the source code from the link https://github.com/apache/cassandra and then built using ant and imported into eclipse following the steps of the link http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/development/ide.html. After changing the source code I built it using the command

> ant cleanall

It runs perfectly inside the eclipse. However when I export the project outside of Eclipse and try to run using the command

> sudo sh bin/cassandra -R

then it runs the previous version of the code and no change reflected. I have googled for solving this problem but still did not find any solution. Please anyone can help me to find the mistake I am doing here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just running the clean task. Instead, you should run the ant jar or just run ant which will invoke the default jar target. This will take a full build and start the cassandra from the build directory.

Comment: I also tried using just ant but the result was the same. However, I find out the problem. When I run ant it invokes the snapshot.jar from the build directory. So now I need to update the snapshot which can be done using maven. Is there any alternative way to update the snapshot without using maven? Because Cassandra is an ant project and when I convert the ant project into maven project lots of errors appear. I have to add all the library jar files as a dependency in the .pom file. Cassandra's source contains a lot of jars and other dependencies and so it is time-consuming to do it manually.

Comment: @SantaMariaShithil you can import the ant project into eclipse by choosing new -> other->Java project from an existing Ant buildfile . This will fix your issue of solving dependency and all that.

Comment: Can I update the snapshot.jar using ant? I tried to do it using ant but can not.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by update. Can you accept my answer if it helped you? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally, I find the solution and of course your answer helped me. The problem was in the ant's build.xml file.